# systemd error "failed to start service: unit service is not loaded properly: exec format error"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I can execute the exact `ExecStart` command from the shell and it works, but for some reason in this service file this doesnt work-- any ideas?

error:

```
Failed to start previewapi.service: Unit previewapi.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status previewapi.service' for details.
```

systemd .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description = preview-api
After       = network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/previewapi
ExecStart   = /usr/bin/java -jar /srv/previewapi/gn-preview-api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

ExecStop    = kill -INT $MAINPID
ExecReload  = kill -TERM $MAINPID

# In case if it gets stopped, restart it immediately
Restart     = always

Type        = simple


[Install]
# multi-user.target corresponds to run level 3
# roughtly meaning wanted by system start
WantedBy    = multi-user.target
```

Ubuntu 18.04.

`sudo journalctl -u previewapi` says:

```
Aug 15 10:00:28 ubuntu-bionic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/previewapi.service:18: Executable path is not absolute:
```

Comment: You probably need to put the arguments in quotes: `/usr/bin/java "-jar /srv/previewapi/gn-preview-api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar"`

Comment: @assylias tried it-- same error. but thx for the suggestion!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem wasn't the `ExecStart`, it was the `ExecStop` and `ExecReload` sections-- they need to be absolute as well.

Final version:

```
[Unit]
Description = preview-api
After       = network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/srv/previewapi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /srv/previewapi/gn-preview-api-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT $MAINPID
ExecReload=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID

# In case if it gets stopped, restart it immediately
Restart     = always

Type        = simple


[Install]
# multi-user.target corresponds to run level 3
# roughtly meaning wanted by system start
WantedBy    = multi-user.target
```

Comment: Just a minor note: in systemd v239+, the paths no longer need to be absolute; however, absolute paths are still recommended.

Comment: @Micah Could you help me out with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671161/unit-xxx-service-is-not-loaded-properly-exec-format-error-on-ubuntu18-04-creat